# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined error in a controlled-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, datepicker, controlled-component

I'm trying to get a date as user input through a controlled component but always running into this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". This is the piece of code that's causing the error. I'm using the `react-datepicker` module to get the Date input as when I try to use the HTML input `type="date"` i'm unable to disable previousdates.

```
import React, {Fragment,useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link,withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'; 
import {addTask} from '../../actions/task';
import { addDays } from 'date-fns';

const TaskForm = ({addTask}) => {
    const [formData,setFormData] = useState({
        description:'',
        due_at:'',
        toBeReminded:''
    })

    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addTask(formData);
    }

    const onChange = e=>setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    const {description,due_at} = formData;
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h1 className="large text-primary">
                New Task
            </h1>
            <form className="form my-1" onSubmit={e=>onSubmit(e)}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="descr">Description:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" id="descr" placeholder="Task Description" name="description" value={description} onChange={e=> onChange(e)}/>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="due_date">Due Date for Task:</label><br></br>
                    <DatePicker id="due_date" minDate={addDays(new Date(), 1)} id="due_date" name="due_at" value={due_at} onChange={e=> onChange(e)} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="reminder">Set Reminder:</label><br></br>
                    <input type="radio" id="yes" name="toBeReminded"  value="true" onClick={e=> onChange(e)}/>
                    <label htmlFor="yes">Yes</label><br/>
                    <input type="radio" id="no" name="toBeReminded" value="false" onClick={e=> onChange(e)}/>
                    <label htmlFor="no">No</label><br></br> 
                </div>
                <input type="submit" className="btn btn-dark my-1" value="Submit" />
                <Link className="btn btn-light my-1" to="/tasks">Go Back</Link>
            </form>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

TaskForm.propTypes = {
    addTask:PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default connect(null,{addTask})(TaskForm);
```

Comment: This means `e.target` is undefined. Try `console.log(e)` in the `onChange` function to try to identify when it is undefined.

Comment: That part is known to me, but I've tried various thing but none worked. Why is it failing to identify it when used in DatePicker component?

Comment: Try to break it down. To start with, do you get an event. What does `console.log(e)` return?

Comment: Got this: SyntheticEvent {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, nativeEvent: InputEvent, type: "change", target: input#descr, …}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs for [`react-datepicker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker), it doesn't look like its `onChange` receives an event, but the date.

You should use a separate handler for the date change handler since they expect different signatures.

```
const onChange = e => setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]:e.target.value})
const onDateChange = date => setFormData({...formData, due_at: date})
```

There's a lot of other solutions that would work if you really want to stick to one change handler, but I recommend just creating two like above.

But.. you could do something like this (I don't really recommend this):

```js
const onChange = e => {
  if (typeof e === 'object') {
    setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]:e.target.value})
  } else {
    setFormData({...formData, due_at: e})
  }
}
```

Or since you're declaring new inline functions already (its unnecessary by the way, just do `onChange={onChange}` unless you use the following approach) you could do this:

```js
const onChange = (name, value) => setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]:e.target.value})

// Regular inputs
onChange={e => onChange('input name', e.target.value)}

// Date input
onChange={date => onChange('input name', date)}
```

The bottom line is: you have to pay attention to what `onChange` is expected to receive. It will differ depending on the input type or the library implementation.